# Problems setting scope when requesting access token for directory API

Tags: google-oauth, google-directory-api

Trying to set the scope when I grab the access token, I just keep getting back the same error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

when setting scope as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`.

Also, the Google OAuth2.0 Playground does no have this scope at all in the list. Does this scope not even exist? What am I missing here?